# How to make sure, that my custom URL protocol is used?

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol, nsurlsessionconfiguration

According to the documentation of `NSURLSessionConfiguration::protocolClasses`, there is no guaranty, that my custom url protocol will be used. How can I ensure, that it is used whenever I set it to `protocolClasses` property?

> Prior to handling a request, an NSURLSession object searches the
>   default protocols first and then checks your custom protocols until it
>   finds one capable of handling the specified request. It uses the
>   protocol whose canInitWithRequest: class method returns YES,
>   indicating that the class is capable of handling the specified
>   request.

I can't set an array with single URL protocol, because it has logic for `canInitWithRequest:` method and might not handle all request.

```
NSArray *currentProtocolClasses = sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses ?: @[];
NSMutableArray *protocolClasses = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:currentProtocolClasses];
[protocolClasses insertObject:[CustomURLProtocol class] atIndex:0];
sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses = protocolClasses;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the docs say that, it's a bug.  Please file one.  The logic is actually much simpler than what is described there.  Basically what the OS does is this:

```
NSURLProtocol *protocol = nil;
for (Class protocolClass in sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses) {
    if ([protocolClass canInitWithRequest:request]) {
         protocol = [[protocolClass alloc] init];
    }
}
if (!protocol) {
    fail
}
```

So as long as your protocols are listed first, they'll get priority.  (For NSURLConnection, that bit of the doc was also wrong; your registered protocols are always asked first, before any of the built-in protocols.)

If you don't need to handle standard protocols, it is sufficient for you to do this:

```
sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses = @[[CustomURLProtocol class]];
```

You cannot force a URL protocol to be used.  The protocol will be used if and only if its `canInitWithRequest:` class method returns YES for the request.  If you want to make a different protocol handle a request (e.g. if you want to define a custom URL scheme that really uses a normal https request), then you would typically do so by writing a protocol that rewrites the URL and reissues the request in a new session that does not have your protocol handler class installed.

Alternatively, you can reissue the request in a session that does have your handler installed so long as you modify the request in some way so your protocol handler knows to return NO from its `canInitWithRequest:` method when it sees the request a second time.  (Otherwise, you'll get infinite recursion.)

Comment: Hi! Could you, please, change the example code to `sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses = @[[CustomURLProtocol class]];` in order to be more generic? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, sure.  Done.

Comment: Regarding "the array will always be empty or nil": I create default sessionConfiguration. Its protocolClasses array already contains 5 OS protocols: `_NSURLHTTPProtocol`, `_NSURLDataProtocol`, `_NSURLFTPProtocol`, `_NSURLFileProtocol`, `NSAboutURLProtocol`. I need to add my `CustomURLProtocol`. Whenever my `CustomURLProtocol` returns NO in `canInitWithRequest:`, the app must fallback to OS protocols.

Comment: Ah.  I guess I'm remembering wrong about that.  I'll edit that, then.